Como configurar decimales en columna de tabla DB Browser for SQLite
Tengo un inconveniente con una tabla TablaTotalPagosDiarios que posee las columnas: 'DESTINO', 'DETALE', 'FORMAPAGO', 'IMPORTE_TOTAL' Y 'DATEFECHA'; como inserté la tabla: CREATE TABLE TablaPagosDiarios ( DESTINO TEXT(50) NOT NULL, DETALLE TEXT(100) NOT NULL, FORMAPAGO TEXT(50) NOT NULL, IMPORTE_TOTAL DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL, DATEFECHA DATE );; luego inserto los datos desde un datagridview con Visual Basic.Net: ` Private Sub btnRegistrarPago_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegistrarPago.Click
Dim DGVPagosDiarios As New DataGridView
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
conn.Open()
End If
Dim DATE_FECHA As Date = Date.Today
 Try
     ' Iniciar la transacción
     Using transaction As SQLiteTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
         For Each fila As DataGridViewRow In Me.DGVPagosDiarios.Rows
             If Not fila.IsNewRow Then ' Verificar si no es una fila nueva
                 If fila Is Nothing Then
                     MsgBox("Ingrese datos")
                     Exit Sub
                 Else
                     ' Insertar en TablaInsertarVentas
                     Dim insertQuery As String = "INSERT INTO TablaPagosDiarios (DESTINO, DETALLE , FORMAPAGO, IMPORTE_TOTAL, DATEFECHA) VALUES (@DESTINO, @DETALLE, @FORMAPAGO, @IMPORTE_TOTAL, @DATEFECHA)"
                     Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(insertQuery, conn, transaction)
                         cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESTINO", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("DESTINO").Value))
                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DETALLE", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("DETALLE").Value))
                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FORMAPAGO", Convert.ToString(fila.Cells("FORMAPAGO").Value))
                         Dim importe As Decimal
                         If Decimal.TryParse(fila.Cells("IMPORTE_TOTAL").Value.ToString(), importe) Then
                             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMPORTE_TOTAL", importe)
                         Else
                             MsgBox("Error de valor decimal:")
                         End If
                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEFECHA", Convert.ToDateTime(DATE_FECHA.Date.ToString(fila.Cells("DATEFECHA").FormattedValue)))
                         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatementType", "Update")
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                     End Using

                 End If
             End If
         Next
         ' Commit de la transacción si todo se ejecuta correctamente
         transaction.Commit()
         'MsgBox("DATA INSERT SUCCESSFULLY")
     End Using
 Catch ex As Exception
     Dim transaction As Object = Nothing
     ' Rollback de la transacción en caso de error
     If transaction IsNot Nothing Then
         transaction.Rollback()
     End If
     MsgBox(ex.ToString)
 Finally
     ' Cerrar la conexión después de completar todas las transacciones
     If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
         conn.Close()
     End If

 End Try

End Sub; como podrán apreciar la tabla en la base de datos está configurada para Decimal, desde VB.Net envio los datos especificamente para la columna 'IMPORTE_TOTAL' como Decimal, sin embargo en la tabla me lo imprime como numero entero; desinstalé e instalé la tabla nombrada en cuatro oportunidades y sigue el mismo inconveniente, intenté Click derecho en la pestaña de la columna 'IMPORTE_TOTAL' seleccioné 'Edit display format' me abre un cuadro de dialogo con el titulo 'Choose display format', tiene un Select, seleccioné 'Decimal number', me muestra este resultado en un cuadro:'printf('%d', "IMPORTE_TOTAL")' y le doy Click al botón 'OK'; el tema es que no se modifica nada, sigue las celdas de dicha columna mostrándose como entero, resolví poner un textbox abajo del datagridview para pasar el valor a la columna como decimal: Private Sub txtIngresarImporteTotal_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtIngresarImporteTotal.KeyDown
'Me.DGVPagosDiarios.Columns("IMPORTE_TOTAL").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Dim valor As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(txtIngresarImporteTotal.Text, valor) Then
        ' Buscar la primera celda vacía en la columna "IMPORTE_TOTAL" y asignar el valor del TextBox
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DGVPagosDiarios.Rows
            If row.IsNewRow Then Continue For
            If row.Cells("IMPORTE_TOTAL").Value Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells("IMPORTE_TOTAL").Value.ToString()) Then
                row.Cells("IMPORTE_TOTAL").Value = valor.ToString("N2")
                FormatoPagosDiarios()
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Else
        ' Manejar el caso en que el valor del TextBox no sea un decimal válido
    End If
End If

End Sub`, pero me carga la clumna del datagridview con coma y no punto, ya no sé como modificar esto, podría presumir algun fallo de la base de datos ? Es muy aventurado esto pero no se que pensar; recurrí a Mónica IA y me contestó esto: 'Entiendo tu problema. Parece que la configuración de formato de visualización en DB Browser for SQLite no se está aplicando correctamente para la columna IMPORTE_TOTAL. Aunque intente establecer el formato de visualización como decimal, parece que el formato no se aplica como se espera.
Dado que estás utilizando DB Browser para SQLite, es posible que la configuración de formato de visualización no esté siendo aplicada correctamente debido a un error en la herramienta.
Una posible solución para este problema sería asegurarte de que el formato de visualización se aplique correctamente directamente en tu aplicación en lugar de confiar en la configuración de DB Browser for SQLite. Puedes formatear los valores como decimales directamente en tu código al mostrar los datos en tu aplicación, asegurándote de que se muestren correctamente.'; en fin, si alguien pudiera sugerirme una salida para este inconveniente, lo agradeceré.

deje de leer cuando le preguntaste a la IA.. ahora.. los numeros van con puntos en sistemas.. si tu numero va con una coma, es muy probable que se haya interpretado mal.. no hay un bug, hay un problema de "localizacion" de tus datos... empeza por ahi...

gbianchi<> Agradezco tu respuesta, podrías precisar un poco más con referencia a problema de 'localización' de los datos, he creado 24 tabla con consulta SQL para mi aplicación y ninguna tiene este problema con la visualizacion en decimal, solo en esta. Gracias y espero una respuesta favorable.

y solo en esta tenes decimales o en todas???

gbianchi<> de las 24 tablas en 8 tablas no inserto decimales(Registrarse, InicioSesión, CategPrincipal, CategSecundaria, ProcedimientosAlmacenados, CodeRecuperacion, DatosPersonales y RecuperaconPass, para ser un poco más preciso, creo la tabla TablaPagosDiarios con consulta SQL y tengo este inconveniente, si la creo con el sistema de crear de la aplicacion me muestra como decimal pero me genera inconveniente con la fecha,  la consulta SQL de crear está arriba

ordena tu problema. Que tabla tiene problemas.. todas??? que quiere decir el sistema de crear de la aplicacion? no ves decimales en ningun lado? el importe que mandas tiene decimales? si tenes problemas con las fechas, cada vez mas convencido que tu programa esta actuando en un lenguaje (el de tu pc) distinto al que maneja la db... no hay un bug, hay un problema ahi, pero tu pregunta esta tan complicada que no se que contestarte...

gbianchi<> solo en esta tabla tengo el problema, consulta SQL para crear:  CREATE TABLE TablaPagosDiarios
(
DESTINO TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
DETALLE TEXT(100) NOT NULL,
FORMAPAGO TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
IMPORTE_TOTAL DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
DATEFECHA DATE
); , me refiero el la columna IMPORTE_TOTAL cuando inserto los datos no se visualizan como decimal, solo como entero (ni punto ni coma) y me refiero al creador de tabla del sistema de la aplicacion en DB Browser for SQLite, con esta forma(sistema) selecciono IMPORTE_TOTAL como NUMERICO en el DataType, : 'Añadir comentario' no permite explayarme.

podrias hacerme el favor de decirme que le estas mandando en el campo importe? que datos? de paso, no se que es el creador de tabla, porque basicamente es lo mismo! sqlite es una base simple, y el browser que tiene tambien es simple, y por detras, ejecuta las querys, no es que crea la tabla con eso...

de paso, si queres nombrar a alguien aca, se usa la @ y el nombre... me entero de tus mensajes porque soy moderador electo, si no, ni los veria..

gbianchi<> En el FormPagosDiario con un DGVPagosDiarios, columnas 'DESTINO' (cargo desde combobox), ´DETALLE' (cargo en la celda), 'FORMAPAGO' (cargo desde combobox), 'IMPORTE_TOTAL (cargo desde textbox) y 'DATEFECHA' en automatico, realizada la carga del DGVPagosDiarios desde el boton 'Registrar Pago' se envia los datos a la TablaPagosDiarios, cargo IMPORTE_TOTAL desde textbox para asegurarme con la configuracuion de este y datagridview que los valores sean decimales, elin conveniente es en la tabla. Pasible disponer un correo para enviar el codigo completo del formulario a analizar config?

mi correo es publico, sin embargo, yo no voy a revisar todo tu codigo, si no lo que me muestres en la pregunta. Eso de revisar y codificar es mi trabajo :). vuelvo a preguntar, como mandas eso a la db? y como lo devuelve la db? y por sobre todas las cosas, va con un punto o una coma como separador decimal? probaste mandar de las dos formas? de ninguna se muestran los decimales?

gbianchi<> El DGVPagosDiarios está cinfigurado en DefaultCellStyle>Format; "N2"para que coloque '.', si eligo como divisa coloca ',' y agrega signo pesos , como sea que lo envie a la columna IMPORTE>TOTAL de la tabla me muestra como entero el valor que envie, no aplica para decimal excepto lo que comenté anteriormente en la construcción de la tabla desde su constructor, sin consulta SQL, todas las tablas creadas en SQLite fueron con consulta SQL y ninguna con este inconveniente, incluídas 2 aplicaciones más construídas, por eso mi duda con respecto a esta tabla o base de datos. AGRADECIDO.

si bueno.. no entiendo nada de lo que me decis.. es muy confuso.. esperemos que otro usuario te pueda entender... te hice un par de preguntas y me contestaste cualquier otra cosa... te pregunte varias veces, como mandas el campo importe.. a mi como lo mostras no me dice nada.  tampoco me dice nada de como generas la tabla, porque deberia ser exactamente igual. Tampoco entiendo porque decis que en otros lados funciona, entonces hacelo como en esos otros lados. suerte con esto.

De todas formas, MUY AGRADECIDO por tu tiempo y conocimiento. Espereré otra opinión o respuesta si la hay. Gracias

P / D: Para todos los Desarrolladores de esta importante Comunidad, considero que todo lo expuesto arriba está demasiado claro mi consulta y planteo del procedimiento en general, si Yo estoy equivocado mil disculpa, traté de ser lo más especifico posible para no confundir a nadie Mil gracias
